# How to call a get method with parameters coma in it

Tags: android

Well the problem i am facing is that i have a string i have an api like below which contains coma in it.

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mmm/api_android/xxx.php?nos=2&names=y,z&ids=1,2
```

When i am trying to make this api call its showing error.

The class i am using for api call is below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
public class ServiceHandler {

    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public ServiceHandler() {

    }


    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) 
    {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }


    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params) 
    {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) 
            {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } 
            else if (method == GET) 
            {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) 
                {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

and in my activity i am calling the api inside an asynctask, like below:

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {   ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        String jsonStrResponse = "";
        String str_toHitURL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mmm/api_android/xxx.php?nos=2&names=y,z&ids=1,2" ;
         jsonStrResponse = sh.makeServiceCall(str_toHitURL, ServiceHandler.GET);
        Log.d("ResponseSit", "> " + jsonStrResponse);

    return jsonStrResponse;
   }
```

why is it showing error? All i could find is that its because of - i have coma in the parameters. So, why isn't it working and how to solve it?

Comment: What error? Please post stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any problems with comma in its conventional form, consider using url-encoded value.
encoding: `,` => `%2C`
decoding: `%2C` => `,`